# Firebase retention not counted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase for android. However, there is one problem. The retention measurement is not performed properly. It used to work properly before. But from a few months ago, all figures were at 0%. I can't figure out why.

There are many users who actually use the app. Still, it doesn't make sense to say that retention is 0%. Even I am using my app

I want to know which event is based on retention. Also how i would like to solve the problem

here is retention of my app

[image: retention screen shot]

Comment: Hmm... that looks unusual indeed. Can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, so that they can have a look?

Comment: I'll try! Thank You!